# How to share variable between two post methods in a same js file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a post method to grab some data from a form. I then have to render another form which has a different post route. I want to use the variable I got from the first post method in the new post method.

I have a post method to grab the variable `username`

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username
  res.render('add_user', {username: username})
});
```

Now I want to use it in a different post method:

```
router.post('/add_user', function(req, res) {
  // I want to use the username variable here
})
```

Note: both the post methods are in the same file named `index.js`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the request to contain the username, rather than trying to share it on the back end?

Comment: Would you consider using a [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)?

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but it's not likely you actually want to do that - unless you only ever have a single user accessing your server

Comment: If these are endpoints are protected, a common method might be to expect a token to be sent up from the client in the request. You could define an Express middleware function which decodes that token, gets the user's ID, and queries whatever database you are using to store user information. You could take that object you get back and stick it on `req.user` to access it in the endpoint, and `res.locals.user` if you have to share it across middleware. Perhaps a better method would be to either (a) expect that username is sent in the request, or (b) query the DB where necessary.

Comment: For my point (b) above, the added benefit of using middleware is not having to waste time/increase latency querying a DB in every single endpoint. Middleware allows you to query once and then make the user object available to every endpoint that uses that middleware.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. First way would be for the second request to pass in the username.

But if you need to maintain a variable on the server and use it between requests, just put it outside of the handlers. Something like this:

```
let globalUsername= "";
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  globalUsername = username;
  res.render('add_user', {username: username})
});

router.post('/add_user', function(req, res) {
   res.send(globalUsername);
})
```

Not a very good solution though; unless you will have only 1 user hitting your website. If you have multiple users, then you need a way to identify them. Common ways include the client passing the username (or a token representing the user) on every request, or a cookie, etc. Look into sessions, cookies, JWTs, and other auth mechanisms.

But if you just want to share a variable across a couple of different requests, just put the variable on the global scope (or anywhere where both handlers can read it.)